# Return rows and total count of returned rows in ORACLE, PHP

Tags: php, oracle, count

I have SQL query:

```
 $query = "SELECT DISTINCT f.ID,  b.NAME, a.USER_ID, b.PARENT_ID
             FROM b_disk_simple_right s, b_user_access a, b_disk_object b, b_file f
                WHERE s.ACCESS_CODE = a.ACCESS_CODE
                AND a.USER_ID = ".$userID."
                AND b.CREATE_TIME > trunc(sysdate)-200
                AND s.OBJECT_ID = b.ID
                AND f.ID = b.FILE_ID
                AND b.DELETED_BY=0";

    global $DB;
    $res=$DB->Query($query,true);
```

I need to get total count of returned rows. I am not able to use oci_num_rows function. How to do this?

Comment: You need to find count of rows returned by a select query right??

Comment: Yes, I need count of returned rows

Answer (score 3):

Below one will gives you the number of rows count

```
 "select count(*) as count
    from
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT f.ID,  b.NAME, a.USER_ID, b.PARENT_ID
                 FROM b_disk_simple_right s, b_user_access a, b_disk_object b, b_file f
                    WHERE s.ACCESS_CODE = a.ACCESS_CODE
                    AND a.USER_ID = ".$userID."
                    AND b.CREATE_TIME > trunc(sysdate)-200
                    AND s.OBJECT_ID = b.ID
                    AND f.ID = b.FILE_ID
                    AND b.DELETED_BY=0
                    )"
```

Comment: But after executing this script, will I be able to access, ID, NAME and other rows returned by select? Or I will get only count?

Comment: @MarciSM No not possible to access.

Comment: I need to access these rows together with count. It is possible to create two queries - one returns count, other returns rows. But is it possible by using only one query?